# Genymotion - which IP set in etc/hosts file for access host's local webserver via domain?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

in original emulator I can push own etc/hosts file with list of host's (PC) local domain with this IP address:

10.0.2.2    web.loc

Which IP I must use for Genymotion emulator (network in virtual machine setting is set as "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter", IP in simulated Android machine is 192.168.56.101. I try 192.168.56.1 but this not work.

Thank for the help.

EDIT:

I used NAT instead of Host-Only for network and now I can connect to host PC via its real IP address.

Comment: test this ip in your app for connect to localhost: 10.0.3.2

Answer (score 9):

`10.0.3.2` is the localhost IP from genymotion vm machine.

Comment: thanks Ken, setting it to 10.0.3.2 really worked! many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can open `cmd` then typing `ipconfig`.
You will see VitualBox Host-Only Network's ip that is you need!

[image] 
[image]